# Server error when invoking a NodeJS lambda function via API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which takes an uploaded file and writes it to s3. I want to be able to use this lambda function via an API call to /upload. When I test the lambda function on its own, it works. When I send a request from a Rest client though, I get internal server error.

I have this lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    let recieved_request = JSON.stringify(event.img);
    let recieved_request_imageId = JSON.stringify(event.imageID);
    let recieved_request_ext = JSON.stringify(event.fileExt);
    let recieved_request_folder = JSON.stringify(event.folder);

    recieved_request = recieved_request.slice(1, -1);
    var filePath = recieved_request_imageId + "." + recieved_request_ext.replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
    let buffer = Buffer.from(recieved_request.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');

    var params = {
        Key: filePath,
        Body: buffer,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        Bucket: "uploads"
    };

    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else {
            var res = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            };

            res.body = "Uploaded";
            callback(null, res);
        }
    });
};
```

I have an API gateway with POST /upload which should invoke this function. I think I need to set it as a lambda proxy but I have tried all manner of {proxy+} in the path.

I have the following permissions on the lambda:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "a4bbfad3-5c9a-5814-8031-97848b9d56a5",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:079898059699:function:UploadDocument",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:079898059699:tht5jn7lm4/*/*/upload"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't seem to make progress, it's hard to find proper logs, and all the docs for setting it as a lambda proxy assume it's the older (better) AWS interface.

Comment: Could you please post CloudWatch logs for both the lambda execution and the API Gateway invocation?

Comment: i’m having difficulty setting an arn that’s valid for the logs... all the docs are for a different ui - ideas?

Comment: You could try to enable logging using the CLI? Check this [method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-stage.html)

Comment: You can locate the error by looking at the CloudWatch logs of the lambda function. If you see an error there, then debug Lambda, if not then there is a problem with API GW.